# How to update the value of a specific column of every row in DB with the output of a function that was passed in the original value.

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

For example: if you wanted to replace in each row the value of a column with the value after being run through a hash function.

In my case I have saved many URLs in a column that have 302 redirects and I want to save where they redirect to after passing their current value into this function:

```
def finalURL(original):
    output = requests.get(original)
    output.url
    return output.url
```

I am relatively new to Python and the closest examples I can find are not written in Python (cannot translate).

Additionally I've seen several posts on how to iterate through a db and print every value in a column, but no explanation on how to change that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your hash function available in SQLite, you have to [create a user-defined function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function):

```
def finalURL(x):
    return ...

db = sqlite3.connect(...)
db.create_function("finalURL", 1, finalURL)
```

Then you can simply use it in queries:

```
db.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET url = finalURL(url) WHERE ...")
```

Comment: This worked great!


I had seen create_function yesterday during my searching but didn't know how to use it while passing in values to a python function. I'm really glad I learnt how to do this!

Thank you greatly!